# Want to fetch latest record from the list of records in kibana using DSL query

Tags: kibana, kibana-6

We are using the ELK v6.6 version.

We have requirement in Kibana that we have list of records which are displaying in the Kibana data table. We need to display last updated record on top of the table. For which we are using below DSL query but which is not working.Can you please help us to resolve this issue.

```
    {
  "query": {
    "match_all": { }
  },
"aggs": {
"actual_trans_type.keyword": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "@timestamp"
    },
    "aggs": {
            "top_hit": {
                "sort": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": {
                            "order": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "size": 2
            }
        }
        }
     }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCpde.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBHC.png

Comment: Why don't you just click on the timestamp column in the table? It will reorder the table into descending order of timestamp.

Comment: According to my requirement, I want to show latest record from thousand of records while  records are displaying in the KIbana table first time itself.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the visualization, click on the `timestamp` column head to sort it in the descending order and then save the visualization. Now you will have the table in the descending order of `timestamp` field by default.